# AppDynamics email digest NOT include all events

Tags: email, hash, alert, appdynamics

I use **AppDynamics email digests** to report slow transactions from some specific business transactions once an hour. The business transactions are the customized ones that matches written regex in URL and work fine. However, I got some **blank** emails and also some events **missed** in the digested email which makes the reports unreliable. AppDynamics official document dose not have much details about email digest. Any ideas? Thanks a lot.
[blank email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcVUw.png)
[events missed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mocMh.png)

1. try change the email digest frequency -- not work
2. check the email digest configuration -- not found any questions
3. Appdynamics document -- not enough information

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.